# Bloquear acesso a arquivos de determinados diretórios caso não esteja autenticado

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Como bloqueio o acesso de determinados diretórios se ele não está autenticado?

Por exemplo

Tenho minha url

www.meusite.com/login

O usuário ainda não está autenticado

Então não quero que ele possa acessar qualquer arquivo .js, imagem, .css do diretório

www.meusite.com/principal/js/arquivo.js

Teria como?

Comment: Acredito que de uma forma fácil não teria, da pra fazer isso facilmente por htaccess, pelo .net talvez daria pra fazer uma página que gere como se fosse uma arvore (mapeamento) da pastas e arquivos e bloquear os arquivos por htaccess,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione em seu aquivo web.config a seguinte diretiva:

```
<location path="Caminho/Para/Pasta/Publica">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

### Explicação

- `location.path` é o local/pasta que deseja bloquear;
- `deny.users="?"` bloqueia o acesso dos usuários anônimos.

### Exemplo

Para o seu caso, você poderia negar tudo e em seguida liberar somente o que os usuário podem acessar. Veja um exemplo:

```
<location path="Content">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Content/Arquivo.js">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Nessa caso a primeira diretiva bloqueia todos os usuários a acessarem a pasta `Content`. Já a segunda, permite apenas o arquivo `Arquivo.js`.